# Excel filter formula for multiple criteria and value in array

Tags: arrays, excel, filter, excel-formula

I'm trying to filter some information from one table, but I need the criteria to look for some info inside an array. I'll give an example to try to explain what I need:

[image]

I need to get everyone from **Array1** `E2:E4` that is listed on **TABLE1** `A2:C4` and has **Monday** and **Yes** on their respective columns.

Hope that makes sense and that somebody will be able to help me on this one.

Thanks a lot!

Tried using filter formula but I can't make it work with the array as a filter.

Comment: This isn't a site to get free work done, at least show something you've tried. Your going to need "filter" + "and".

Comment: You won't get the list shown in `E2:E4` with `Monday` & `Yes`, also what do you mean by `Anyone` ? explain more

Comment: Thanks for replying @Monofuse. I can filter using either conditions but can't filter using the array (E2:E4). I can only use filter with a singular condition, that is "=", and not to get a value inside a list or multiple values.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out @MayukhBhattacharya. I need to filter the list from Array E2:E4 (that's an example of data, not actual data). I need to filter the TABLE1 using this array as a condition, but I need to get all the lines to compare with TABLE1 and get the names under the array that satisfy the conditions of Day and Include.

Comment: @FerPavao ah understood, that is what I was anticipating, still the output will show only `Fulano` as per the screenshot given. It wont give `Ciclano`

Comment: That is exactly what I want but I can't get excel to use the array as a condition to filter.

Comment: @FerPavao try this `=FILTER(A2:A4,(B2:B4="Monday")*(C2:C4="Yes")*ISNUMBER(XMATCH(E2:E4,A2:A4)))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MayukhBhattacharya. It works if you have only one result but it won't spill. For example, if Ciclano had Yes it wouldn't appear on this filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across the same challenge. Here's how I got it to work. I hope it solves the problem

`=FILTER(A2:C4;(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A4;E2:E4;0))*(B2:B4="Monday")*(C2:C4="Yes")))`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

What about this, it will give you the **required output**,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=FILTER(A2:A4,(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(E2:E4)=A2:A4),ROW(E2:E4)^0)=1)*(B2:B4="Monday")*(C2:C4="Yes"))
```

---

Here are other alternatives:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=LET(_table,A2:C4,
_name,INDEX(_table,,1),
_day,INDEX(_table,,2),
_include,INDEX(_table,,3),
_array,E2:E4,
x,--BYROW(_name,LAMBDA(a,(SUM(COUNTIFS(a,_array))>0))),
FILTER(_name,(x=1)*(_day="Monday")*(_include="Yes")))
```

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K2</kbd>

```
=LET(_table,A2:C4,
_name,E2:E4,
_map,MAP(INDEX(_table,,1),LAMBDA(m,IF(SUM(COUNTIF(m,_name))>0,m,""))),
_other,(INDEX(_table,,2)="Monday")*(INDEX(_table,,3)="Yes"),
FILTER(TAKE(_table,,1),(_map<>"")*_other))
```

---

Comment: That is great @Mayukh Bhattacharya. This solves it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @FerPavao Sounds good, glad to know you were able to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with user who mention this place is not for homework, but I know useful information about it.

Microsoft explain how use "AND" into filter in the following [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60662&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Basically use `*` operator, with this info I mimic your homework to return values using filters.

[image: sheet]

Formula:

```
=FILTER(A2:C4, (B2:B4=D6) * (  C2:C4=D7),"")
```

D6 = Monday
D7 = Yes

Comment: Thanks for replying. The way you're presenting works because you're using only 1 cell or value as reference. What I need here is to use an entire array to compare with, that is E2:E4.