# Find multiple cells in a list between two workbooks and then delete those row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find

I'm trying to find and match the 3 cells from the Sample1 workbook in the right into the list from the Sample0 workbook in the left, and then delete those rows.
Is there a way to do it?

[image]

The 'find' feature only lets me do one cell at a time, unfortunately.

Comment: Not with a formula.  You can flag them if they exist, but formula will not delete.

Comment: To search multiple records, you can refer either of these solved posts. also with formula it won't delete you either need to do it manually or use vba automation

Comment: [Search_Multiple_Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71445085/how-to-search-multiple-names-from-a-range-and-return-multiple-records-in-excel) or this one [Search_Multiple_names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74253833/excel-filter-formula-for-multiple-criteria-and-value-in-array)

Comment: Do you think Python or VBA would be better to do it if I want to make a program to find and delete it?

Comment: Either would do what you want.

Comment: I think you can use Power Query as well, its an alternative option.

Comment: Not delete, but you can have the filtered data in another place (tab for example) via excel formula. Delete you can do it with VBA or Power Query or any other program that integrates with Excel.

Comment: I'd been studying how to use Excel formulas for a few weeks now, so can I use Excel formulas in conjunction with Python (pandas, openpyxl?) or Power Shell to create a final program? Or it's not recommended to do this?

Comment: see below - ta .

Answer (score 1):

screenshots/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9g4gOVOasqztE42zJag?e=quODKu) refer:

[image: Sample for cell refernces - function and vb code]

---

**w/ VBA**

```
=LET(x_,F2:OFFSET(F2,COUNTA(F:F)-2,0,1,1),FILTER(x_,--NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(x_,B2:OFFSET(B2,COUNTA(B:B)-2,0,1,1),0)))))
```

*Caveats:*

- *Assumes you have Office 360 (due to `let` and `filter` functions)*
- *Shorten by removing dynamic range as required (assumes no populated cells below samples 1,2 otherwise) e.g. `= Filter(F2:F11,--not(isnumber(match(F2:F11,b2:b4,0))` would do for known ranges `f2:f11` and `b2:b4` sample 2,1 respectively*
- *Update function for alternate locations (separate workbooks/sheets etc.) as req.*

---

**with VB**

```
Sub remove()

'#####nice to have######
original_selection = ActiveCell.Address 'to return to original selection after run
Call reset '(for testing: remove to deploy)
'#####            ######

Range(Range("f2"), Range("f2").End(xlDown)).Select
Set region = Selection.Cells
Range(Range("b2"), Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Select
Set region2 = Selection.Cells

'#####nice to have######
ReDim myArray(0) 'purely for providing message RE: cells removed at end of procedure
On Error GoTo err_trap 'best practice
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'asthetics
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'efficiency, better yet: store calculation mode and revert to this
'#####            ######

k = 1 'for myArray (purpose: see comment above)

For Each cell In region 'this is sample 2
    For Each cell2 In region2 'this is sample 1
        If cell2.Value = cell.Value Then
            '#####nice to have######
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve myArray(k) 'purpose: comment above
            myArray(k) = cell.Address & ": " & cell.Value
            '#####            ######
            
            If cell.Offset(1).Value = "" Then
                cell.ClearContents 'for last cell being checked in sample 2: just remove if matched in sample 1
            Else
                Range(cell.Offset(1), cell.End(xlDown)).Select 'select cells below matching cell in sample 2
                Selection.Copy 'copy them
                cell.Select 'now select matching cell, sample 2...
                ActiveSheet.Paste 'and paste over this those from below
                Selection.End(xlDown).Select 'now select final cell (duplicated)
                Selection.ClearContents 'and remove it
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

'#####nice to have######
Range(original_selection).Select 'return to selection to where it was before running
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
myArray(1) = "removed cells: "
MsgBox Join(myArray, vbCrLf) 'provide message RE: which cells removed (address / value)
Exit Sub

err_trap: 'in unlikely event of error - :) - restore environment
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    MsgBox ("error dude ") 'notify user RE: error as req. ta
'#####            ######


End Sub

'#####should have: testing######
Sub reset():
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Range("F2").Select 'assumes sample 2 values (original) are in col L per screenshot
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("L2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
'#####            ######
```

*Caveats*

- *Remove 'nice to have' and 'should have' parts as req.*
- *Assumes user can update cell references appropriately e.g. Workbook().Range() references for samples located in separate sheets/workbooks as req.*

[image: GIF illustrating VB option]

---